# Decimal button on NumPad returns "¾" as a symbol (190) in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, keydown

I use this code to forbid a second entry of '.' but it doesn't work, because e.Key returns 190 and when I cast it to char/string it returns "¾".

```
private void FromBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (VirtualKey.Decimal == e.Key) this does not work?!?!
        if (???? == ((Char)e.Key).ToString())
        {
            if (true == FromBox.Text.Contains("."))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The KeyDown event gets *virtual keys*.  Virtual key codes have nothing to do with characters, the char they produce (if any) depends on the user's language.  You are just using the wrong event to do this, use the [CharacterReceived event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.core.corewindow.characterreceived.aspx) instead.  And keep in mind that some users will type a comma instead of a period.

Comment: There is no such event in windows phone 8.1 textbox

Comment: Following the link, note that it is an event on the CoreWindow class.